# Use Nvidia optimus card for HDMI output

Tags: hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

I have an ASUS laptop which has a 17" 1600x900 and Intel HD 3000 / Nvidia gt540M card

Whenever i connect to my 24" 1080p samsung TV, no app uses the nvidia card and what i'm forced to play games with intel HD3000 (which is super bad)

I want to force use the GT540M card for HDMI output

Can someone guide me how to do that?

Comment: What makes you think you're *not* getting the GT540M involved?  How can you tell?

Comment: Because when i disconnect the HDMI and start the game, the performance is top notch but when using the HDMI, the peformance drops...and the temperature doesn't rise (which usually increased when the nvidia card is on)

Comment: I would expect a performance drop from moving to a higher-resolution screen, so that's not really indicative of anything.

Comment: the performance is same even when i use the samsung display on 1366x768. And i don't think performance should drop from 90 to 10 in a change from 1600x900 to 1920x1080. Should it?

Comment: Have you proprely set profiles for your games in Nvidia Control center? You may try switching your card temporarily in BIOS.

Comment: @t_virus Does it work with BIOS tweaks etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/282734/how-to-disable-nvidia-optimus-on-a-dell-xps-15) (and its answers), which I posed in May 2011 and have not yet received a satisfactory answer for. The short version is: Optimus allows mixed-mode rendering by allowing the powerful Nvidia GPU to write (e.g. output video) directly into the frame buffer of the Intel IGP.

Based on my experience with optimus, it is possible that the Intel graphics adapter is hard-wired to the HDMI output port on your laptop with a second frame buffer that is not accessible to the Nvidia GPU. If this is the case, it will not be possible under any circumstances to use the Nvidia GPU for that particular output.

To confirm this, I would use the Nvidia control panel to force GPU rendering of the application you want to run, and then confirm that the GPU is used for that application on the laptop's built-in screen. Then try the same thing on the HDMI port and check that the GPU is being used. If running the application on the monitor connected to the HDMI output results in the GPU not being used, you are most likely out of luck.

You can use the [Nvidia Optimus State Viewer](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/26992-optimus-test-tools-finally-in-users-hands/) to determine with certainty whether the Nvidia GPU is being used.

Comment: For what it's worth, on my ThinkPad W520 with NVidia Optimus (Quadro 1000M), with a DisplayPort->DVI adapter (there is no HDMI port) I am able to run 3D accelerated applications (using the NVidia card) on the DVI monitor. -- I haven't tried DisplayPort->HDMI yet (just hooked it up that way for the first time today -- got here because I'm trying to figure out how to get audio out of the HDMI screen -- man, these GPUs are lame).