# advice on displaying in 3d on TV via laptop

Tags: 3d-graphics

how do i get my nvidia card on my laptop to display on my secondary screen (3D TV) using nvidia 3d vision. when viewing 3d material via TV the laptop displays it can only display through primary display

Comment: Does your laptop have Optimus?  Some Optimus configurations are such that [the HDMI port only works with integrated Intel video](http://superuser.com/questions/479914/use-nvidia-optimus-card-for-hdmi-output) - if that's the case, you won't get 3D output via HDMI as the nvidia card isn't outputting to the HDMI . . .

Answer (score 1):

Your secondary display would also need a refresh rate of 120hz for 3d.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the model of your video card, but most video cards these days should have a spare HDMI port you can use.  If so, you plug an HDMI cable from your video card to the TV, and your computer should take care of the rest.

If your video card doesn't have an HDMI port, you'll need it to have a spare DVI port and a DVI to HDMI converter, so you can do the same as explained above.

If you need to manage the displays once you're connected, you can do it from the Control Panel > Displays option.