# No image via hdmi with Samsung laptop and Windows 8

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I could use a little help with this.

If got a brand new Samsung NP550P7C-T09BE which I hook up to my 32LG3000 TV via HDMI. The same cable and same TV used to work just fine with my previous Compaq laptop. But if I hook up the Samsung Series 5 laptop, I do get a connection but no image, it's completely black.

De TV tells me it's getting a signal, the laptop shows me it's found a second screen and names it 32LG3000 (correctly) and the sound now plays via the TV.

I just replaced the Nvidia drivers with the latest, but no success.
The laptop appears to have two display adapters though, the Intel HD Graphics 4000 and the Nvidia GeForce GT630M. If I disable the first (device manager), the connection with the TV is lost... I'm wondering if there's a conflict between the two.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a system with switchable graphics - this [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/479914/use-nvidia-optimus-card-for-hdmi-output) suggests that such systems might not be able to use the Optimus/nVidia card for HDMI output . . .

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot form reading that, though no solution for me yet...

Answer (score 0):

Graphical output is done via Intel graphics, therefore with deactivating it your connection is lost. The nVidia graphics card only give performance if needed, but no additional screens resolutions or else. There may be somethign incompatible with what Intel provides over HDMI and your screen supports, but regarding their docs HDMI shoudl work in your case. Have a look at the following:

> What three independent display configurations are supported?
>   What is the maximum resolution supported in three independent displays configuration?

http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, that explains a lot and I got a better understanding of the working of the graphics of my laptop. As of yet though, I've been unable to puzzle an image out of my LG TV. But... I tested the laptop on a different TV (Samsung) and with a different cable: hdmi workt instantly! So, the problem is the cable, or that the LG TV can't handle the HDMI signal it gets from the laptop (although I always thought HDMI was a standard?) I hope, to test this again, with the cable I just comfirmed to work with my Samsung TV, on the LG.