# Sleeping Dogs Definitive Edition [game] is set to use my NVIDIA GT 630M but uses the integrated graphics processor

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics, optimus

I have this set up:

**Operating System:** Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1

**CPU:** Intel Core i5 2450M @ 2.50GHz Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology

**RAM:** 8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)

**Graphics:**

- ThinkPad Display 1366x768 (1366x768@60Hz)
- Intel HD Graphics 3000 (Lenovo)
- 2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M (Lenovo)

This notebook of mine (Lenovo Z470) has NVIDIA Optimus technology. I recently installed Sleeping Dogs Definitive Edition via Steam (local files transferred from my work notebook which doesn't have Optimus).

In *NVIDIA Control Panel -> Manage 3D Settings -> Program settings*, I specifically set this game to use the **High-performance NVIDIA processor**.

But it does not use the NVIDIA GPU at all. The GPU Activity tray icon doesn't show it being used. And the game is very laggy even on windowed, low settings. The NVIDIA OPtimus Test Viewer confirms that while my other games (PPSSPP emulator, NBA 2k, Medal of Honor) use the NVIDIA GPU, Sleeping Dogs does not use it.

Now I've seen a similar question here ([Intel HD Graphics 4000 is used instead of nVidia Geforce 630M for old game?](https://superuser.com/questions/578148/intel-hd-graphics-4000-is-used-instead-of-nvidia-geforce-630m-for-old-game)), but the difference is that this user's game actually utilizes the NVIDIA GPU.

I have GeForce Experience installed and my NVIDIA GPU has the latest drivers. What could I possibly do to resolve this? Please help. Thank you.

## Update. Steps I've done as per the advise of Square Enix support:

1. I ran the actual exe file (sdhdship.exe) as an Administrator already.
2. I right clicked sdhdship.exe->Run with graphics processor->High-performance NVIDIA processor.
3. Updated my NVIDIA GPU drivers to the latest.
4. Windows Updates are the latest.
5. Updated DirectX using directwebsetup.exe from the Microsoft.com web site.
6. Reinstalled both Steam Client and game (re-downloaded the files).
7. Updated my sound card drivers to the latest.
8. I set it to my screen's resolution (1366x768).
9. I set it to windowed mode.
10. I disabled VSync from NVIDIA Control Panel and from the in-game Advanced Display Options.
11. I again verified the integrity of the game cache via the Steam app.

Nothing worked and here are the Benchmark results which clearly shows the game is still using the Intel graphics card.

[image: Benchmark results]

Comment: Reinstall both graphics drivers or install the latest versions available from Lenovo

Comment: @Moab Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have GeForce Experience installed and my NVIDIA GPU driver is the latest. Also, I don't see how reinstalling them is going to help since this GPU runs well on all my other games (Tomb Raider included). Thank you.

Comment: If other games work then is is a problem with that particular game, suggest you contact them for support.

Comment: Can you right click the game (I know it's Steam, but you should be able to create a launcher for it), and then choose to 'Run with graphic processor->' then select your NVidia GPU? I've had to do it that way specifically for a few games (Steam included) with my Optimus tech .. I've yet to encounter any graphics application (game/music/video/etc.) that ONLY runs on my IGP vs. the NVidia GPU in my laptop though .. I've also had to switch my default GPU to my NVidia over my Intel which forces everything to run through it (at the cost of my battery) .. ?

Comment: @txtechhelp I've tried that step, it didn't work. I checked my BIOS setup, I only had an option to use the IGP or Optimus. No option to select the NVIDIA one. How else could I set it as the default graphics card? Thanks.