# computer hardware ... what are the things needed to make my cpu run at the highest frequency

Tags: windows-10

my laptop CPU Type is AMD A8-5545M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics it runs on 1.70GHz and the turbo core speed is 2.70GHz but when im playing video games it runs on 1.05GHZ but i want it to run at the highest frequency when im playing video games... for maximum performance

Comment: Are you on battery? If so, the processor is probably throttled to extend battery life. You could try setting the power plan to High Performance, which instructs the processor to run as fast as it can, but you'll get less battery life. If that doesn't work, please read http://superuser.com/a/855852 (the answer describes GPU throttling, but the same can apply to the CPU). You might also be suffering from thermal throttling—if the cooling system can't extract enough heat (not uncommon on thinner systems), it'll slow down when it gets too hot to avoid burning itself out.

Comment: i dont think its the heat ... immediately i open a game i wanna play the cpu speed reduces like the turbo core goes off and it starts running at 1.05GHz

Comment: That seems to be a TDP limit to me. It appears that when the IGP gets stressed, it clocks down the CPU. Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

Download a program such as Speccy to check your temperatures and see if you are going over around 80 Celsius or so. If you are, then further increasing the CPU speed will cause physical damage to your computer. If not, you should then ensure that Windows is set to High Performance power plan and look in your BIOS (you can access this by pressing Del, F12, or another key when your computer starts up) for settings regarding power saving and performance and CPU speed. If you see an option for fan control, set it to be constantly very high to cool off your CPU when it runs at a faster frequency. You can test your computer's maximum performance and maximum heat output by downloading a tool such as Prime95 and watching your temperatures.

However, you should note that most of your games will probably be limited by your computer's GPU or graphics processor. What kind of games are you trying to play? An A-series APU won't play the latest AAA games well.

Comment: games like call of duty advanced warfare, crysis 3 and all .... any game i open it reduces

Comment: its like this... before i open any game on my laptop .my cpu will be running at the highest frequency but when i try opening any game it reduces to a lower frequency...was thinking about increasing the cpu voltage so it would be able to stay at its turbo core speed

Comment: https://rtechsupport.org/kb/perf/

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you need to max out the CPU frequency? It won't necessarily boost performance in the game. The CPU will run as fast as is needed.

You can make the CPU stay at it's highest frequency by adjusting you power saver settings. However be aware this won't boost you frame rate. It will just make your computer run hotter.

Comment: yeah i want better performance on my games

Comment: If it needed extra CPU performance then the OS would automatically increase the frequency. Your game is most likely limited by your GPU, so forcing the CPU to run faster won't make any difference.

Comment: okay, i know my GPU helps, but when i open the game i wanna play my  cpu goes from its turbo core which is 2.70GHz and reduces to its normal frequency and that is 1.70GHz  and after a while like 3 or 2 mins the cpu speed goes down to 1.05GHz ...when it goes to that frequency the game starts lagging

Comment: Have you checked the temp. That does sound like it might be throttling the CPU because it's getting too hot. Have you tried using power saving config to increase minimum frequency to 100%? Also I assume you're not using it on battery. You shouldn't game on battery power.

Comment: yeah its not on battery. power saving to 100%?

Comment: tried that. same result

Comment: So you set "Minimum Processor State" to 100% and it's still dropping the frequency?

Comment: yea i did what u said same result

Comment: Next things I would check. 1) CPU temp, does slowdown correlate with temp increase. 2) Faulty fan, related to temp. 3) BIOS updates.

Comment: i think i tried that too, but don't think hp gives that option to control your fan speed